# Classe não encontrada em controlador

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer o uso de duas classes em um controlador (FranchiseRepository e OrderRepository), porém essas classes não estão sendo encontradas no meu controlador. Segue abaixo o código das classes e o *stacktrace* do erro:

**Erro**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OrderController**

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use \App\Services\JsonService as Json;
use \App\Repositories\FranchiseRepository as Franchise;
use \App\Repositories\OrderRepository as Order;

class OrderController
{
    protected $franchise;
    protected $order;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->franchise = new Franchise;
        $this->order = new Order;
    }

    public function sendOrders(Request $req, Response $res)
    {
        // select all active and enabled to send data to nappsolution franchises
        $franchises = $this->franchise->getNappFranchises();
        var_dump($franchises);
    }
}
```

**FranchiseRepository**

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Franchise;

class FranchiseRepository
{

    protected $franchise;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->franchise = new Franchise;
    }

    public function getNappFranchises()
    {
        return $this->franchise->select('napp_network_id', 'napp_user', 'napp_pass', 'napp_id')
                    ->where([
                        ['active', '=', true],
                        ['napp', '=', true]
                    ])
                    ->get();
    }
}
```

**OrderRepository**

```
namespace \App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Order;

class OrderRepository
{

    protected $order;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->order = new Order;
    }
}
```

Comment: No código não vi nenhum problema. Dentro do servidor a classe **FranchiseRepository** está dentro do namespace especificado (App\Repositories)? Confere a hierarquia de diretórios por gentileza.

Comment: O problema era que eu não tinha carregado o namespace App\Repositories no autoload psr-4 do composer haha